# Why would a modern browser allow internal resources to be loaded from an external page

Tags: xss, csrf, chrome, firefox

Recently someone announced that several Arris surfboard models lacked any form of authentication to perform functions such as reboot and factory reset a modem with a single http call.

Read more on that here if you want: https://blog.wjd.io/motorola-surfboard-hack

My question is why would a modern browser allow internal resources to be loaded from an external page. What viable use cases are there that would outweigh the obvious security implications of this issue?

Comment: While the link describe this as XSS, to me it sounds more like CSRF. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Anders: yes, definitely CSRF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> functions such as reboot and factory reset ... why would a modern browser allow internal resources to be loaded from an external page

Most of today's routers and other networked devices will be administrated through a web interface. This means that there is some web server with a web application running on the device and the user is using the browser to access this device the same with as (s)he is using any other web page. This web interface then offers ways for the user to reboot the system or similar by clicking the specific links in the web interface.

But by default a browser allows lots of interactions between web pages of different origin. You can click on a link on one web page to go to another page. Or you can embed images from one page into another page etc. The browser itself has no knowledge what is an internal page and what is an external page and which pages are allowed to link/embed to another and which not. Thus the web applications have to do the checks by themselves, i.e. check if a request to the device is caused from a different origin and don't execute it in this case.

Thus the one which was overly permissive in this specific case was not the browser, but the web application running at the router. It should have checked the origin of the request and not execute it if it was caused by some other site (cross origin request).

Unfortunately this kind of bugs are very common. Such devices are often developed with a tight budget and security only adds costs but not functionality. Apart from that most developers are not even aware that the web is mostly permissive by design and that they should add the needed restrictions to the device.

Since such bugs are that common it would of course be nice if browsers would at least include some protection for such broken devices, like limiting access from external to internal sites. But unfortunately there are actual use cases for such cross-origin requests to local IP which then would break. And then are issues with DNS and proxies. And probably more issues. For a deeper discussion see [this Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378566) where they discuss about this issue since about 2 years.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest the browser is the one wrong here. But I fully believe its dumb for the browser to allow a resource from an external publci ip load a resource from a private, non publicly route able address. Yes the fault here is on Arris for a crazy design, but the browser should warn or block it too. IMHO.

Comment: @Wjdavis5:  There are no clear rules of interaction which the browser can use to restrict access: would it have been ok if the request was caused by a different device in the same network (i.e. link from internal wiki)? How about different network but both networks are private? How about access to the routers external IP (works with some routers from inside)? How about a link from inside a mail? Or from the bookmark? ...

Comment: Well yes there arent any rules. Another problem. We arent talking about all of your example situations though. This one is very specific. I load a page on the internet and it requests to load an image from a private ip address. I cannot think of a single situation where that is a valid use case. I'll probably write a chrome extension to block it.

Comment: @Wjdavis5: see the discussion at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378566 which also includes some examples where such cross-origin to a private IP like 127.0.0.1 is used in practice: spotify web player, dropbox. And please note that your extension need also handle the case that attacker.example.com might actually resolve to a local IP like 10.0.3.1.

Comment: Hey great find! I was looking around for a discussion on there first. I'll be reading that. At first glance it looks like they agree with me that it needs 'fixed'

Comment: @Wjdavis5: yes, but they also include several examples of what will break if they fix it. It is just really hard to make something more secure which was not designed with security in mind - i.e. the  web which is permissive by default.

Comment: Every example of 'what would break' deals directly with a 127 address. I can see that. I want all traffic to my internal private address space blocked. I think that is a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally the web administration service for most routers is bound to the LAN facing interface with at least basic HTTP auth. So the is strange for Motorola. So they must have either too small a memory footprint so they went with a HTTP server that does not do auth or they went with a language that has a HTTP web server module without HTTP auth built in and the developers didn't build it in.

Just a note. If your router ever gets compromised and it is only LAN facing, then your local hosts must be the source. At least primarily. With this form of attack, you can see the basics of how remote attackers prey on http users to compromise behind firewall assets.